# curl shows a greater-than sign instead of uploading a given file to a given server

Tags: linux, command-line, curl

I want to upload a file to a WebDAV server within Linux command line. The standard recommendation for this is to use curl in the following way:

```
curl -u mail_address:password -T filename.ext https://my_server.com/dav/filename.ext
```

When I execute this command, it shows me a greater-than sign in the command prompt, as if my command was incomplete, no uploading happens:

```
$ curl -u mail_address:password -T filename.ext https://my_server.com/dav/filename.ext
$ >
```

However, it doesn't tell me what I have to type here, and no positing on the internet (e.g. [Is there a way of uploading to box.com storage via the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/757792/is-there-a-way-of-uploading-to-box-com-storage-via-the-command-line)) ever mentioned that you have to type some additional stuff after this command. Any ideas how to fix this? *mail_address* and *password* refer to an existing account, and *filename.ext* refers to an existing file on my machine.

P.S.

- Ubuntu 14.04
- curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet your password has a quotation mark (`'` or `"`) in it.  Bash thinks that you've begun a multiline string/quote, so it gives you your [`$PS2` prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193660) on the second line, which is usually `>`.

Make sure that your arguments are all [properly escaped](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160602215631/http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).

Example:
If your password is `$jkl;'"`, then you can escape it with double quotes like `"\$jkl;'\""`.

Alternatively, you can run your command like this:

```
curl -u mail_address -T filename.ext https://dav.box.com/dav/filename.ext
```

Then, `curl` will prompt you for a password like so:

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ curl -u mail_address -T filename.ext https://dav.box.com/dav/filename.ext
Enter host password for user 'mail_address':
```

[Documentation](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160702191748/https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> `-u`, `--user <user:password>`
>
> Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication.
>   Overrides `-n`, `--netrc` and `--netrc-optional`.
>
> If you simply specify the user name, curl will prompt for a password.
>
> The user name and passwords are split up on the first colon, which
>   makes it impossible to use a colon in the user name with this option.
>   The password can, still.
>
> When using Kerberos V5 with a Windows based server you should include
>   the Windows domain name in the user name, in order for the server to
>   successfully obtain a Kerberos Ticket. If you don't then the initial
>   authentication handshake may fail.
>
> When using NTLM, the user name can be specified simply as the user
>   name, without the domain, if there is a single domain and forest in
>   your setup for example.
>
> To specify the domain name use either Down-Level Logon Name or UPN
>   (User Principal Name) formats. For example, EXAMPLE\user and
>   user@example.com respectively.
>
> If you use a Windows SSPI-enabled curl binary and perform Kerberos V5,
>   Negotiate, NTLM or Digest authentication then you can tell curl to
>   select the user name and password from your environment by specifying
>   a single colon with this option: "-u :".
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.

Comment: Indeed, there was a quotation mark in my password. Thanks.